# "Feel a poulpe in your throat!" Does it look like a sailor's swearing?

Tags: phrase-requests, offensive-language

It's for my friend who is somewhat of a writer. One of his characters is a skipper, old sea dog swears like this: "Дохлый осьминог тебе в рот и чтоб попал туда через жопу!" [lit. (let) dead octopus (be) in your mouth and got there back asswards] I've translated it this way: *"Feel squishy poulpe (or a cuttlefish or something) in your throat, through your guts, from your bottom!"*

It should sound funny and english-sailor-curse like too. I doubt if my adaptation is good enough. Sorry if it's in a way rude.

I need to get a phrase of the same meaning I've literally translated alreday but in **real english**, not that weak thing I came with like.

Comment: Arr ya scurvy seadog, i've not wandered to guess the faintest notion what in the duck-knee'd dung munchin' crap sack a "poulpe" is

Comment: Yes, you're right it's too frenchlike)))) cmon help me with those squids! hey maybe squid is the right word.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. You've provided a literal translation, but is there some sort of other meaning to the phrase? Are you looking for us to translate it or is this a proofreading request or what?

Comment: This unpleasant notion seems similar to the observation [“Something crawled up your ass & died.”](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Something%20crawled%20up%20your%20ass%20and%20died!) (sometimes posed as a question:“What crawled up your ass & died?) from which you could perhaps get to: “May a spiny eel/sea urchin crawl up your worthless ass & eat its way to your trifling throat before laying eggs, dying, & then rotting there!”(it’s not “English-sailor-like” but spiny eels/sea-urchins might be more of a curse than squishy squids, which some home-sick pirates might actually enjoy!)

Comment: But why does your friend have to write these things in English, which is clearly not his/her native language?

Comment: Your literal translation seems largely serviceable, though I'd have guessed 'back asswards' meant the octopus had reversed in so that it's ass was on his tongue. 'Ass' is American English too. How about 'I hope a rotting octopus crawls so far up yer arse that its suckers pull yer last tooth from its lonely socket.'

Comment: People, it's a klondike of brilliant ideas (no sarcasm) I feel myself like scrooge mcduck in his gold coin pool! Thank you all!!

Comment: aparente001, he writes funfiction on tv series, anime and so on. Now it's something about british navy. Suddenly he wants to get some native color for a certain phrase. As you can see I'm not keen on english enough to serve his needs. So we need a help :)

Comment: Spagirl Good, really good. I'm excited!

Comment: 'Poulpe' is unrecognizable in monolingual English. It looks vaguely like 'pulp' which is not the impression you're trying to give. I think you intend 'octopus' because that's what it is in French. Not every French word is in English.

Comment: Yes it is not. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (personally) wouldn't use squishy.  If you want to keep poulpe, perhaps 'Poulpe (and any other sea-critters) choke (the breath from) your (miserable) throat after wormin' through y'er guts, aft first.'

Probably not the best, but hopefully in the right direction.  Making an effort to provide feedback based on experience as a sailor in the Navy.  Not the same as a salty Captain of old, but closer than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

"May a scuttle-fish wriggle its way through your guts, entering trough your arse, exiting through your mouth, you slimy bottom-feeder you..."

"May Neptune shove his trident where a sea gherkin would never show its face!"

"Never have I seen such a slimy dribble of ink such as the likes of you!"

Hehe, this was fun. (I also appologise if I  cause offense.)